# Why isn't this for loop executing in a typescript function?

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why the for loop in this function never runs. I wrote what gets returned next to each console log. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
export function arrayChange(inputArray: number[]): number {
    let total = 0;
    console.log('inputArray.length', inputArray.length) // returns 3
    console.log('inputArr', inputArray[0] <= inputArray[1]) //returns true
    for(let i = 0; i > inputArray.length - 1; i++){
        console.log('hello') //never runs
        if(inputArray[i] <= inputArray[i + 1]){
            total += inputArray[i + 1] - inputArray[i] + 1
        }
    }
    return total
}

console.log(arrayChange([1, 3, 4])); //returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition used in your `for` loop is wrong.

It should be `i < inputArray.length` The condition used in the code snippet will evaluate to false as 0 (which is the initial value of variable `i`) is less than `inputArray.length` Therefore your `for` loop never executes.

Read more about `for` loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0):

You have your condition backwards:

```
for(let i = 0; i > inputArray.length - 1; i++){
}
```

Your array has length 3, so what you start with is:

```
for(let i = 0; i > 3 - 1; i++)
```

`i` is thus never larger than 2. Thus the loop doesn't do a single iteration.

You probably meant this instead (note less-than, instead of greater-than):

```
for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++){
}
```

You now start with this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3 - 1; i++)   // 0 < 2 - first loop iteration
for(let i = 0; i < 3 - 1; i++)   // 1 < 2 - second loop iteration
for(let i = 0; i < 3 - 1; i++)   // 2 < 2 - no more iteration!
```

Assuming you want to actually iterate *all* array elements and not skip the last one, we're not done yet.

This means that the condition is still wrong (use `<=` or leave the `- 1`):

```
for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
}

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)   // 0 < 3 - first loop iteration
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)   // 1 < 3 - second loop iteration
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)   // 2 < 3 - third loop iteration
```

So, there you have iterated all (3) array elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
i < inputArray.length
```

The bracket error is causing this issue. Your loop counter starts at 0 so loop never runs since condition is never met so counter is not incremented

Answer (score -1):

You're initializing the iterator at 0, but trying to evaluate i `0` from the *back* of the array with `>`, so 0 will never be greater than inputArray.length - 1, so it never runs.

Change `>` to `<` in your `for` loop.

```js
function arrayChange(inputArray: number[]): number {
    let total = 0;
    console.log('inputArray.length', inputArray.length) // returns 3
    console.log('inputArr', inputArray[0] <= inputArray[1]) //returns true
    for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++){
        console.log('hello') //never runs
        if(inputArray[i] <= inputArray[i + 1]){
            total += inputArray[i + 1] - inputArray[i] + 1
        }
    }
    return total
}

console.log(arrayChange([1, 3, 4])); //returns 0
```